# WSO2 Cloud Controller does not deploy cartridges

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

I am trying to install WSO2 cloud controller. My goal is the open virtual machine with cloud controller and then run sample cartridge on that vm. I followed documentation from website http://docs.wso2.org/display/Stratos200/OpenStack.

When i install stratos cloud controller it could create new vm on open stack and starting that instance. However it is not deploying cartridges to new vm and i could not see any errors on logs. You could see the logs at the below.

TID: [0] [CC] [2013-11-05 00:30:18,493]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl} -  Starting new instance of domain : wso2.appserver.domain and sub domain : __$default {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl}
TID: [0] [CC] [2013-11-05 00:30:26,647]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.cloud.controller.iaases.OpenstackNovaIaas} -  Successfully associated an IP address xx.xx.xx.xx for node with id: RegionOne/84d37fed-e595-4b4c-9cd9-35cac661f6bc {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.cloud.controller.iaases.OpenstackNovaIaas}
TID: [0] [CC] [2013-11-05 00:30:26,968]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl} -  Instance is successfully starting up in IaaS openstack.     IP Address(public/private): xx.xx.xx.xx       Node Id: RegionOne/84d37fed-e595-4b4c-9cd9-35cac661f6bc {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umut,

I think there is a confusion in the terminology you use. What you see is starting up WSO2 application server cartridge instance. 
Infact there is nothing went wrong in your setup according to the logs.

Let me explain you what happens inside.
When you start the setup, it will have the appserver cartridge xml deployed inside Cloud Controller. Since this is multitenant cartridge, it will create the appserver cluster at the start of the setup.
So it spawns the cartridge instances using cartridge image(You have uploaded/ created in Openstack).

If you log into the Stratos controller dashboard, you can see appserver under multitenant cartridges and subscribe to it.
Then you can access it using the url displayed.
You can find user guide at[1].

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/Stratos200/GUI+User+Guide#GUIUserGuide-SubscribingtoaCartridge

Comment: Thanks Lahiru,
Problem was my cartridge instance, when i download cartridge from wso2 it has worked. I have one more question. When i look at architecture (http://docs.wso2.org/download/attachments/26841314/Stratos2-Carbon-Cartridge.png?version=1&modificationDate=1368617466000) it is connecting SC for AS config. How could it connect to SC, because there is no information about SC in cartrige.

Comment: I see. Glad that you have solved the problem. AS server which resides inside cartridge instance joins SC and ELB as WKA(Well Known) members.

Configurations(SC ip/port) are passed as payload to the spawning VM instance.